# checkbox appeared gary and checked in Galaxy Built in browser and Maxthon

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-checkbox

When i test my website on my Galaxy S II Built in Browser or Maxthon all check box's appeared Gray and its not Checked its like a gray Checked by default but when i really check it, it turns to Green Color with checked sign on it.

[image]

can i give a general style to all check box's to make them appears like normal check box not appearantly gray checked i need it clear and when check it the checked sign appears on it

Comment: its already an issue
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12693

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's how each browser displays a checkbox for checked and unchecked states.

If you want to change how the checked and unchecked states looks like, I would suggest to use a Javascript plugin to replace them like jQuery UI, or make your own toggle-able buttons.

The easiest way for customizable checkboxes could be using [jQuery UI Button](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox)